# Can't access WordPress functions in file called via Ajax?

Tags: theme-development, functions, ajax

I am trying to reload the fresh posts using jQuery. As far as I know, I can't reload the contents of a div inside the page so I reload a file into that div.

The problem is that my loaded file gives me a **Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_query()**

How can I implement functions to a newly created file inside the theme directory to work properly?

***This is my jQuery***

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
    var SANAjax = function(){

    }
    setInterval(SANAjax, 15000 );
});
</script>
```

***And this is what i have in `reloadhomeposts.php` (I have deleted the content though)***

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=3,4,5&showposts=10"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
.
.
.
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is that your loading the file without loading in the WordPress system and so wp_query() doesnt exist.

Quick fix is to:

`include("../../../wp-load.php");` <-- guessing at the location of the wordpress file.

at the top of the php file.

Comment: Hi Brady, I will check it soon and tell you. So wp-load loads the functions used in wordpress?

Comment: Working! How can I load the plugins too ?

Comment: Yes this loads wordpress. But you need to come up with a way to check if Wordpress is already loaded or not. For example if this is a page template then on normal load circumstances wordpress is already loaded, but not loaded when done via an ajax call.

Comment: as for the plugins that I'm not too sure. Maybe someone else can help here. If you are dealing with a template page then maybe in your ajax call it would be better loading like this: http://example.com/mypage/ then use jquery to just grab the html you need to update. this way everything is loaded that you are going to need

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is to use WP's admin-ajax.php file, instead of your own. See this Codex page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side

Instead of putting the code in a plugin, just put it in your functions.php file.